# How to save multiple checkboxes values in different rows of database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, html-table

I am working on a checkbox table, the submitted data should be saved in the mysql database. There are two columns in the table, auto-increment Id and another one for saving the values of the checkbox.

Currently it is only saving one value at a time even when I select multiple, only the latest one gets saved.
Here's the code:

```
report.php

<?php


$active = "report";
require_once 'pages/header.php';
require_once './functions/schema-functions.php';

$course = Schema::getCourse();
$objective = Schema::getObjective();
?>




<form id="addReport" action ='./functions/report-functions.php' method="post">

<table id="table1" class="table">
    <?php
    echo '<tr><th>Objectives</th>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($course); $i++) {
        echo '<th id = "rotate1">'. $course[$i]->commonName . '</th>';            
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    for ($y = 0; $y < count($objective); $y++) {
        echo '<tr><th class=row-header>'.$objective[$y]->objective.'</th>';

    for ($x = 0; $x < count($course); $x++) {

        echo "<td><input name='check[]' type=checkbox value=c".$course[$x]->courseId."-o".$objective[$y]->objectiveId." id=checked></td>";

        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>

</table>
<input type="submit" name= "submit" value= "Submit"/>
```

report-functions.php

```
<?php


 require_once 'db-connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
{


$conn = DatabaseConnection::getConnection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    if(isset($_POST['check'])){
   foreach($_POST['check'] as $value){
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Report (ColRow) VALUES 
 ('$value')");
  }
    if ($sql->execute(array( ':checked' => $checked))) {
        $conn->commit();
        return true;
    } else {
        $conn->rollback();
        return false;
    }

   }
   }
   }
    ?>
```

I want to save multiple selected checkboxes in different rows of the database and after submit, I want to display the table again with the boxes being checked and the user should be able to make the checks and submit the data again.

Comment: `execute(array( ':checked' => $checked))`  You don't use the `:checked` bound parameter and you don't defined the `$checked` variable.  Honestly, I wouldn't expect _any_ rows to be inserted.  Also, you start the transaction outside of the loop, but commit inside the loop.  That kind of defeats the purpose of having the transaction.

Comment: It is still saving single value, when I select multiple the last one gets saved

Comment: "still" after making what changes exactly?

Comment: I meant the above code is saving a single record, even with the errors which you mentioned

Comment: Can you print exactly how the code should be? to save multiple values in a single submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving the records, you might try like this:

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['check'] ) ){
        try{

            require_once 'db-connect.php';
            $conn = DatabaseConnection::getConnection();


            $sql='insert into `report`  ( `colrow` ) values ( :value )';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );



            if( $stmt ){

                $conn->beginTransaction();

                foreach( $_POST['check'] as $index => $value ) {
                    $result = $stmt->execute( [ ':value' => $value ] );
                    if( !$result ) {
                        throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Failed to execute query %d for %s', $index, $value ) );
                    }
                }

                $conn->commit();
                exit();
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            $conn->rollback();
            exit( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you help with the other part too?

Comment: what "other part"?

Comment: Being able to edit and delete the entries... now when the user submits the table, the page should load the same table with the checked boxes and the ability to make changes and re-submit it

Comment: You might be better to ask a new question with the appropriate code. The "other part" seems like there are several moving pieces, all fairly simple granted but too broad to update the above and for it to still make sense in relation to the initial question.

Comment: Hey @RamRaider can you please help with this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579816/how-to-view-edit-delete-records-from-a-checklist-table-in-php-mysql

Comment: what part are you having problems with? As it stands there does not appear to be any mechanism for editing/deleting items and the code in the new question is the same as above. Explain how you wish to perform the selection of and then editing ( or deletion ) of items - querystring, form???

Comment: Using sql edit, update and delete I would like to proceed with it. As for now it is just saving the data but the next time I load the page the table is blank again.Using sql queries I want it to display the checked boxes for the values in the database and then with edit and update it should save the changes further and delete the entries in the database when I user unchecks a box and then display the updated table again.

Comment: Maybe using if and else in the same functions is it possible? If yes then how would we put it up in the same code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191565/discussion-between-aam-and-ramraider).